# I need to add a value to an array field in a cloud firestore document

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I want to add values to array in Firestore document and get them back as list or array.

This is my code , and it just replace the array value at 0 index , and i made a list and added the value it return boolean .

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
final DocumentReference doc = db.collection("RoomInformation").document(model.getRoomAdmin());

db.collection("RoomInformation").document(model.getRoomAdmin()).update(freshUser).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            doc.update("onlineUsers" , Arrays.asList("user" , facebookUserName)).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    new OurToast().myToast(view.getContext() , facebookUserName + " Join The Room");
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: i made it with arrays.aslist() and i made it with collections.singltonlist() and when another one join the room , it change , i wanna add the new user under the old user

Answer (score 0):

As seen in the offical documentation regarding [arrays](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays):

> Although Cloud Firestore can store arrays, it does not support querying array members or updating single array elements.

Taking the following code snippet as an example:

```
public class ArrayPost {
    String title;
    String[] categories;

    public ArrayPost(String title, String[] categories) {
        this.title = title;
        this.categories = categories;
    }
}

ArrayPost myArrayPost = new ArrayPost("My great post", new String[]{
    "technology", "opinion", "cats"
});
```

We see that using the data structure above, there is no way to perform this query.

One more thing to note, although Cloud Firestore can store arrays, this is an anti-pattern. One of the many reasons Firebase recommends against using arrays is that it makes the security rules impossible to write. I recomand you consider an alternative data structure, where each category is the key in a map and all values are `true`. Please take a look at this example:

```
public class MapPost {
    String title;
    Map<String,Boolean> categories;

    public MapPost(String title, Map<String,Boolean> categories) {
        this.title = title;
        this.categories = categories;
    }
}

Map<String, Boolean> categories = new HashMap<>();
categories.put("technology", true);
categories.put("opinion", true);
categories.put("cats", true);
MapPost myMapPost = new MapPost("My great post", categories);
```

**Edit 13 Aug 2018:**

According to the updated documentation regarding [array membership](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership), now it is possible to filter data based on array values using `whereArrayContains()` method. A simple example would be:

```
CollectionReference citiesRef = db.collection("cities");
citiesRef.whereArrayContains("regions", "west_coast");
```

> This query returns every city document where the regions field is an array that contains west_coast. If the array has multiple instances of the value you query on, the document is included in the results only once.

Comment: thanks alex , i found a note in firestore said : Querying across subcollections is not currently supported in Cloud Firestore. If you need to query data across collections, use root-level collections ... and i don't find any thing about the root level collectios.

Comment: Which is? And is about what?

Comment: "Querying across subcollections is not currently supported" and that's correct. But i don't understand what does this note have to do with arrays. You wanted to add a value to an array. Can you be please more specific?

Comment: simply i wanna make a chat app , i made a rooms and put them in apdater ,and i can't put the online users or the chat in adapter too , cuz they are in fields

Comment: If you have another question, different then the initial one, to follow the rules of this comunity, please feel free to post another fresh question, so me and other users can help you. Do you think that my answer helped you for the initial question?

Comment: not really , and i post another question , thanks alex :)

Comment: Because what you were asking cannot be achieved as you say, you think that my answer did not helped you at all?

Comment: helped in the first part of the question , and i found the firestore is poor in the second part , i still trying to figure out this problem